# Make CylinderGeometry non-hollow

Tags: three.js

I want to draw a normal pie chart with `three.js` and went with the `CylinderGeometry` to do that. 
The problem is, that I want to animate my pie chart. Like if someone clicks on a segment of the pie chart, it should slide out of the pie chart.

The problem is, that this geometry is **hollow** in the inside!
Is there a way to make the `CylinderGeometry` **solid** (non-hollow)? (I know I could draw my own pie chart but I want to know if there is a possibility to do it with the `CylinderGeometry`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LatheGeometry()` or `ExtrudeGeometry()` will help you to build segments of a cylinder. But as you want a non-hollow segments, then `ExtrudeGeometry()` is your choise.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/rm355men/) example

Comment: This doesn't work. If you take a look in the source code on github, it says that it only can extrude geometries from a path shape.

Comment: I've made an example with `ExtrudeGeometry()` and it works totally fine. `Path` has a nice `absarc(...)` method.

Comment: Have you used one of the built-in geometries like me, or did you draw your own shape?

Comment: Thank you for your example! That's what I thought. You used your own created shape to extrude it... It seems like extruding doesn't work with built-in geometries which are not drawn by a path.

Comment: Just in case you need to also rotate the pieces of the pie as you make them, it is easiest to describe the values and colors similar to a chart library, and return a list of the pie parts, using @prisoner849 's approach. See this example which is basically the same approach but makes it a function of values.... http://jsfiddle.net/2dmorzhf/

Answer (score 0):

This is an outtake of my code. 
I am iterating over a json file to get the data, and then this code snippet creates multiple segments.

```
var segment = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5,5,1.5,50,50,false,lastThetaStart,(Math.PI*2)*(jsonData[data].percent/100)),
        {amount: 100, steps: 100, bevelEnabled  : false}),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
            shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
            specular: 0xffffff,
            shininess: 3,
        }));
```

But as soon as I execute the file within my `example.html`, it gives me the following error:

> three.js:26099 Uncaught TypeError: shape.extractPoints is not a
>   function(…)